# How can the `-V` flag be both `--verbose` and `--version`?

Tags: c, flags, getopt

From https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/disk-utils/mkfs.c#L94-L113

```
/* Check commandline options. */
opterr = 0;
while ((more == 0)
       && ((i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "Vt:h", longopts, NULL))
       != -1))
    switch (i) {
    case 'V':
        verbose++;
        break;
    case 't':
        fstype = optarg;
        break;
    case 'h':
        usage();
    case VERSION_OPTION:
        print_version();
    default:
        optind--;
        more = 1;
        break;  /* start of specific arguments */
```

The docs for mkfs say that `-V` is the short flag for both version and verbose. I'm having trouble understanding how this is possible, and am looking for clarity.

`VERSION_OPTION` is defined as `enum { VERSION_OPTION = CHAR_MAX + 1 };` so I'm not sure what char that is.

Comment: "and the source code seems to agree" How? `CHAR_MAX + 1` is not `V`.

Comment: Perhaps, -V is version, when used single, and is verbose, when combined with another flag.

Comment: @tkausl Ok, fair point. Doesn't agree. What I should have said is, I have no clue what `CHAR_MAX + 1` is to know if it is `V` or not.

Comment: `VERSION_OPTION` is returned for the long option `--version`. See the definition of `longopts`. As far as `getopt_long` is concerned, there is no short option for `--version`. It's handled separately, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Drazisil well, `CHAR_MAX` is the maximum value of *any `char`* value, and since it would by necessity be greater than or equal to `'V'`, adding 1 will lead to a value that cannot possibly be `'V'`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look up a few lines.  Before calling `getopt_long`:

```
    if (argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-V"))
            print_version();
```

The code has a special case, not handled by the normal option processing code, for a single argument with the value `-V`. If there's more than one argument, it will fall through that `if` and process `-V` as the `verbose` flag.

One effect of this is that

```
mkfs -V -V
```

prints an error message:

```
mkfs: no device specified
Try 'mkfs --help' for more information.
```

This is also noted in (some versions of) the man page:

> **`-V, --version`**
>
> Display version information and exit.  (Option **`-V`** will display version information only when it is the only parameter, otherwise it will work as **`--verbose`**.)